# Sorting lines of a text file using column with integers -

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I need to sort the lines of a text file using the integer values of one of the columns 
(the first one). 
The file (`coord.xyz`) looks like this

```
9  1  -1.379785  0.195902  -1.197553
5  4  -0.303549  0.242253  -0.810244
2  2  -0.582923  1.208243  1.566588
3  3  -0.494556  0.028594  0.763130
4  1  -0.749005  -1.209878  1.358057
1  1  -0.883509  1.111866  2.882335
6  1  -1.005786  -1.278486  2.719391
7  5  -1.128898  -0.088124  3.508042
10  1  -0.253070  -0.289294  5.424662
8  1  -1.243879  -0.217228  5.247915
```

I used the code

```
import numpy as np

with open("coord.xyz") as inf:
    data = []
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line)==5:
            data.append(line)
f_h = file('sorted.dat','a')
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: data_entry[0])
np.savetxt(f_h, m, fmt='%s', delimiter='    ')
f_h.close()
```

the `sorted.dat` file resulted to be like this

```
1    1    -0.883509    1.111866    2.882335
10    1    -0.253070    -0.289294    5.424662
2    2    -0.582923    1.208243    1.566588
3    3    -0.494556    0.028594    0.763130
4    1    -0.749005    -1.209878    1.358057
5    4    -0.303549    0.242253    -0.810244
6    1    -1.005786    -1.278486    2.719391
7    5    -1.128898    -0.088124    3.508042
8    1    -1.243879    -0.217228    5.247915
9    1    -1.379785    0.195902    -1.197553
```

The `10` is considered as a smaller value than `2`. 
Could someone help me to fix this ?

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you're copying and pasting bits of code from random places without trying to understand them. For example, do you know what the `with` statement near the top does? If so, why aren't you using it again for `f_h`? If not, [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) explains it.

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote is sorting the lines as strings.  Alphabetically 10 comes before 2.

Try writing your lambda as:

```
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: int(data_entry[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you used NumPy to *import* the data as well as to *export* it, you wouldn't have this problem. For example:

```
m = np.loadtxt("coord.xyz", dtype="i, i, f8, f8, f8")
```

Now you've got a 1D array of tuples of the appropriate types, and the default `m.sort()` will sort the tuples in the usual way, which is exactly what you want. So the whole thing reduces to three lines: read the array, sort the array, write the array.

---

But let's show you what you did wrong with your attempt:

```
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: data_entry[0])
```

You're asking it to sort by the first string in the list of strings `data_entry`. So that's what it does. If you want it to sort by that first string *as a number*, you have to tell it that. Like this:

```
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: int(data_entry[0]))
```

And that's it.

---

Also, if you want to read (or write) CSV-like files without using NumPy, rather than writing your own string processing, the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module in the standard library makes your like easier:

```
with open("coord.xyz") as inf:
    data = list(csv.reader(inf, delimiter='    '))
m = sorted(data, key=lambda data_entry: int(data_entry[0]))
with open("sorted.dat", "a") as outf:
    csv.writer(outf, delimiter='    ').writerows(m)
```